# Convert byte slice to int slice

Tags: go

I'm currently trying to convert a `byte` to an `int` so I proceed like this:

```
var d = []byte{0x01}
val, err := strconv.Atoi(string(d))
```

and I get this error:

> strconv.Atoi: parsing "\x01": invalid syntax

I've tried a lot of way without success yet..

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: The raw value of 0x01 isn't an ascii character. Please provide a complete example of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I get the same error if i put []byte{1}

Comment: as you can see there : https://play.golang.org/p/oByoIdY5D3G

Comment: because `0x01` and `1` are just different ways of writing the same value 1.

Comment: It makes no sense to take a single byte with the value of 1 and try to parse it as a decimal number in a string. Are you trying to parse a binary encoding of some sort?

Comment: i'm not trying to parse a binary encoding, i'm just trying to put each value of an int array in a byte array and then to reconvert my byte array in an int array

Comment: Then just convert the bytes to ints, there's no need for parsing strings.\

Comment: And how should i do ?

Comment: The [Conversions spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)
 -- [Conversions in "Effective Go"](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#conversions) -- Is this what you want to do? https://play.golang.org/p/SyLZHggdK-N

Comment: exactly what i wanted thank you a lot !

Comment: @JimB i edited the post, you can put your answer for anyone looking to do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slice already contains a byte value of `1`, not the ascii character `1`, so there is no need to try and convert it to a string.

To convert a slice of `byte` to a slice of `int`, convert each value individually

```
byteSlice := []byte{1, 2, 3, 4}
intSlice := make([]int, len(byteSlice))
for i, b := range byteSlice {
    intSlice[i] = int(b)
}
```

For reference, see the sections on Conversions in the [Go Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), and in [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#conversions).