# Convert Slice of int64 to byte array and vice versa in GoLang

Tags: go, casting

I need to convert a slice of int64 to a byte array in golang. I am successfully able to do so for a single int64

```
var p int64 = -3984171602573983744
fmt.Println(p)
cn := make([]byte, 8)
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(cn, uint64(p))
fmt.Println(cn)
```

How can I implement it for a slice of int64?

To be more precise, I am trying to call a function in a library which writes to a DB, and that function takes a byte array as a param. I have a slice of int64 which I need to convert to a byte array and vice versa. Is this possible?

Comment: You will probably have to loop through and do this 1 by 1

Comment: For each of the int64's loop and store it like `binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(cn[x:], yourUint64)`, where x becomes 0,8,16...as you loop. Your cn should be big enough to take all the data (it'll be some multiple of 8). When you want to read do the reverse `x1 := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(cn[n:n+8])`, where `n` becomes 0, 1, 2..See https://play.golang.org/p/YVQOAG8-Xlm for a simpler muxing-demuxing example

Comment: @Ravi Write that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick :) https://play.golang.org/p/OdRakHIk1PP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert byte slice to int slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178008/convert-byte-slice-to-int-slice)

Answer (score 5):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {

    w64 := []int64{math.MinInt64, -1, 0, 1, math.MaxInt64}
    fmt.Println(w64)

    // Write []int64 to database []byte
    wbuf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := binary.Write(wbuf, binary.LittleEndian, w64)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("binary.Write failed:", err)
    }
    db := wbuf.Bytes()
    fmt.Printf("% x\n", db)

    // Read database []byte to []int64
    rbuf := bytes.NewBuffer(db)
    r64 := make([]int64, (len(db)+7)/8)
    err = binary.Read(rbuf, binary.LittleEndian, &r64)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("binary.Read failed:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(r64)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/4OscSOGZE52

Output:

```
[-9223372036854775808 -1 0 1 9223372036854775807]
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 7f
[-9223372036854775808 -1 0 1 9223372036854775807]
```

Answer (score 1):

For each of the int64's loop and store it like `binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(cn[x:], yourUint64)`, where `x` becomes 0,8,16...as you loop. Your `cn` should be big enough to take all the data (it'll be some multiple of 8). When you want to read, do the reverse: `x1 := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(cn[n:n+8])`, where `n` becomes 0, 1, 2..

See https://play.golang.org/p/YVQOAG8-Xlm for a simpler muxing-demuxing example.

Answer (score 0):

If your machine is also little endian (pretty common), you can use an *unsafe conversion* to do this very quickly (no for loop required). Here are two example functions that handle arrays up to 2^32 bytes long. You can change the code to handle larger capacities.

Of course, this uses the **unsafe** package, so you might want to modify this to return copies instead of using the memory directly. If you're not familiar with unsafe pointers, you can learn [here](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/).

```golang
func bytesToInt64s(buf []byte) []int64 {
    if len(buf) < 1 << 16 {
        return (*[1 << 13]int64)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0]))[0 : len(buf)/8 : len(buf)/8]
    }
    l := len(buf)
    if l > 1 << 32 { // only use the first 2^32 bytes
       l = (1 << 32) - 1
    }
    return (*[1 << 29]int64)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0]))[0 : l / 8 : l / 8 ]
}

func int64sToBytes(buf []int64) []byte {
    if len(buf) < 1 << 13 {
        return (*[1 << 16]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0]))[0 : len(buf)*8 : len(buf)*8]
    }
    l := len(buf) * 8
    if l > 1 << 32 { // only use the first 2^32 bytes
       l = (1 << 32) - 1
    }
    return (*[1 << 32]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0]))[0 : l : l]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am late answering this question but after a lot of searching for a simple answer which does not seem to do some strange magic stuff or unsafe pointer operations, I ended up creating this piece of code. I hope it helps the cause.

```
func convertInt64ToByteSlice(input int64) []byte {
    inputUint := uint64(input)
    ClearOctate8 := uint64(0b_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_11111111)

    result := []byte{
        byte(inputUint >> 56 & ClearOctate8),
        byte(inputUint >> 48 & ClearOctate8),
        byte(inputUint >> 40 & ClearOctate8),
        byte(inputUint >> 32 & ClearOctate8),
        byte(inputUint >> 24 & ClearOctate8),
        byte(inputUint >> 16 & ClearOctate8),
        byte(inputUint >> 8 & ClearOctate8),
        byte(inputUint >> 0 & ClearOctate8),
    }
    
    return result
}
```

You can of course return an array of 8 bytes instead of a slice, but I needed slices so I have used a byte slice as return value. It should also be pretty evident how to use other integer types (like int32 or uint16 etc.) to convert to a byte slice.